# I am using setTypeface for adding custom fonts in my app in the first activity it's working fine but in the second activity it is not working

Tags: android, typeface

I am using 'setTypeface` for adding custom fonts in my app in the first activity it's working fine but in the second activity it is not working
my code is like this

```
Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/eenadu.ttf");
txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdec);
String val=intent.getStringExtra("txt");
txt.setText(val);
txt.setTypeface(tf2);
```

xml code is:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtdec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have you printed value in your textview?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/title"
```

to

```
android:layout_below="@id/title"
```